# How to adjust JavaScript for modal window

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to  make a modal window appear when I click on the button. I wrote a post view and added a button and a W3Schools [script](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) to display the modal window. It turned out something like:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="leftcolumn">
           <div class="card">
         <h2 lang="ru"><%= post.title %></h2>
         <p lang="ru"><%= post.body %></p>
         <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button> <!-- taken from the site -->

         <!-- The Modal -->
         <div id="myModal" class="modal">

           <!-- Modal content -->
           <div class="modal-content">
             <span class="close">&times;</span>
             <p><%= post.translation %></p>
           </div>

         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 <% end %>

 <script>
     // Get the modal
     var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

     // Get the button that opens the modal
     var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

     // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
     var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

     // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
     btn.onclick = function () {
         modal.style.display = "block";
     }

     // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
     span.onclick = function () {
         modal.style.display = "none";
     }

     // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
     window.onclick = function (event) {
         if (event.target == modal) {
             modal.style.display = "none";
         }
     }
 </script>
```

Everything works fine, but only for the very first post. The script processes only the very first button. I think I know why this happens, but how do I fix it? It seems that `getElementById` is taken here when creating variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A couple things... we don't care what your experience level is, we just want well-researched and well-asked questions, that show that you put in the preliminary effort to try to solve it. So, don't apologize, just do your work up front. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" as it explains exactly how to do those things.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` will only ever return the first element that matches the given id. It is generally assumed that each ID given to an element is unique. That is what is happening.

If you need to have a unique modal for each post, then you could append each id of the modal with the id of the post, this ensures they are unique.

You should also get rid of all the global variable for `modal`, `button`, `span`, since they are only ever referencing the same element.

Give your `<button>` and `onclick` attribute and call a function and pass in the unique id of the post, that should let you locate all the appropriate elements for that post.

`<button id="myBtn_<%= post.id %>" onclick="showModal(<%= post.id %>);">Open Modal</button>`

```
function showModal(id) {
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal_" + id);
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn_" + id);
  // show your modal and anything else that happens on click
}
```

You should update `span` to be similarly selectable instead of just having a class.

Hope that helps!